# How to use sed to identify patterns in multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

So i want to convert numbered list from a one specific form to another.

from this form:

```
1. numberedlist
2. one
3. two
```

to this form:

```
# numberedlist
# one
# two
```

I make another changes on that file using sed. hence I want to use sed to identify the first form whenever it happens and without limits meaning even if the numberedlist contains more than 3 items.

My thoughts about doing that are:

**first**: invoke a line containing the pattern (which is a number > a dot > a space.... `'[[:digit:]]\. '`) to the Pattern Space

**second**: invoke the next line to the pattern Space and check if it contains `'[[:digit:]]\. '` or not. and keep doing that until the next line don't conation the Regex.. then replace it with #s. but yes, I don't know if that's even possible.

This is what I'm using now:

```
s/[[:digit:]]\. /# /
```

but yes I know It's not very efficient. I'm still kind of new to the sed world so any help appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: sorry for the confusion guys, my goal is change just the  list index to #. any numbers started from 1. to just #. I just want to convert numbered lists into markdown for autonumbering engine.

I can't use something like `s/[[:digit:]]\. /# /` cause it will change any acurence of the pattern even if It isn't a list.

Comment: This isn't clear enough. How do you get from your input sample to the output you're asking for? Does a numbered list always start with `1. numberedlist`? What happened to 3? Or are you saying you want to drop the first entry in the list, and then for subsequent entries decrement the counter by one? And how are you planning to get sed to do arithmetic? Is your goal, as your question suggests, really "how to use sed...", or are you more interested in achieving the desired result?

Comment: yes the numbered list always start from 1.. and always in this form digt.space. I just need to convert the list numbers to #.

Comment: are you also looking to remove blank lines (as your example appears to show)?  could you have enough lines such that you start getting into 2-/3-digit numbers, eg, 10., 11. ..., 100., 101.

Comment: I edited the question.. I don't want to do any thing to the actual list I just need to convert its numbers to hash

Comment: yes that's a possibility. could be more than 1 digit.

Comment: It *looks* to me as if you're trying to convert numbered lists into markdown for autonumbering. Does your markdown processor not recognize numbered lists already? I know that quite a few of them do.

Comment: Since sed can't count, what about simply `sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*\. /# /'`? Or `[[:digit:]]` if that's important to you.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to "convert numbered lists into markdown for autonumbering". Not It doesn't recognize numbered lists at all

Comment: please update your question with some sample data where you don't want an occurrence of the pattern to be changed; it's best to provide a detailed sample set of data showing as many possible different inputs and the associated outputs, otherwise we get into this back-n-forth in the comments trying to get more details ... and/or you get answers that don't address your actual issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible `sed` solution:

```
sed -r 's/^[[:digit:]]+\. /# /g' <inputfile>
```

- `-r` : treat search pattern as an extended regex
- `/^[[:digit]]+\. /# /g` : look for lines that start with 1 or more digits followed by a period and a space, and if found replace with a `#` followed by a space
- leave all other lines as they are (ie, don't make any changes)

For example:

```
$ cat datfile
1. numberedlist
2. one
3. two
where in the world is waldo
10. pickles
15. jam
# I'm just a comment
sky blue
100. bash
101. ksh
102. csh
72.don't touch this
# rubber ducky
```

And a test run of our `sed` script:

```
$ sed -r 's/^[[:digit:]]+\. /# /g' datfile
# numberedlist
# one
# two
where in the world is waldo
# pickles
# jam
# I'm just a comment
sky blue
# bash
# ksh
# csh
72.don't touch this
# rubber ducky
```

Comment: The `+` is ERE notation supported in a number of non-GNU versions of sed using the `-E` option (similar to grep's `-E`). Of course, POSIX compatibility isn't difficult in this case, so would think that is indeed the preferred alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `awk`:

```
$ echo "1. numberedlist
2. one
3. two
55. fifty-five" | awk '{$1="#"} 1'
# numberedlist
# one
# two
# fifty-five
```

If you want to detect only lines that start with digits:

```
$ echo "1. numberedlist
2. one
3. two
look ma no digit line
55. fifty-five" | awk '/^[[:digit:]]+\. /{$1="#"} 1'
# numberedlist
# one
# two
look ma no digit line
# fifty-five
```

But, if you want `sed`:

```
$ echo "1. numberedlist
2. one
3. two
look ma no digit line
55. fifty-five" | sed 's/^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*\. /# /'
# numberedlist
# one
# two
look ma no digit line
# fifty-five
```

Comment: But, but .. the question was "How to use sed"!  :-) Also, this doesn't recognize the lists within larger bodies of text.

Comment: *this doesn't recognize the lists within larger bodies of text* I don't follow. This will work similarly to `sed` on lines of text. Whatever is the non space part is converted to `# `

Comment: Well, you hadn't yet added the second and third blocks of code when I added the comment. Your first solution would obviously have replaced `look` with `#`.